# Could not load NIB in bundle...MSSTabBarCollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Swift iOS project and I installed [MSSTabbedPageViewController](https://cocoapods.org/pods/MSSTabbedPageViewController) using CocoaPods. I successfully:

1. Created an Objective-C Bridging Header
2. Made one of my ViewControllers a subclass of MSSTabbedPageViewController and implemented the required methods

But When I click the tab that is supposed to present the MSSTabbedPageViewController, the app crashes and gives me the error from the title of this question.

How do I fix this?

Comment: It seems to be a `module` setting problem. If you're using it inside Storyboard, make sure you set the `Module` correctly. If not, then I'd recommend [this](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip) repo that I've used successfully.

Comment: That one looks even better actually, thanks for the tip. Where did you find it/where is the best place to look for libraries like that?

Comment: For me, I like to check Github Explore page for Trending libraries. If you keep watching this for long enough, you'll know almost any kind of good libraries.

Comment: Appreciate it, will be doing that now!